# How to interpret best score from GridSearch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I train different classifiers with different set of data and I need to understand how can I properly measure effectiveness of classifier.

Here's my code:

```python
iris = load_iris()

param_grid = {
    'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'max_depth': np.arange(4, 6)
}

tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target)

tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree_preds = tree.predict(X_test)
tree_performance = accuracy_score(y_test, tree_preds)

print 'Best params: ', tree.best_params_
print 'Best score: ', tree.best_score_
print 'DecisionTree score: ', tree_performance
```

Question is, what actually is a best score from GridSearchCV? And how it differs from results used in `accuray_score` function?

As I understand, `accuracy_score` takes classes of test set and compares it with results predicted by algorithm. The result is the percentage of properly classified items. But what is `best_score_`?

These two values are different and an example output from my script looks like this:

```python
Best score:  0.955357142857
DecisionTree score:  0.947368421053
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` does not take into account your test set (looking closely, you'll see that you don't pass your test set in `tree.fit()`); the score it reports, `best_score_`, comes from a cross-validation (CV) in your *training* set. From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> **best_score_** : float
>
> Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator

This score itself (0.955 in your example) is the mean value of the score in each one of the (default, since you have not specified the `cv` argument) 3 CV folds.

Your `accuracy_score`, on the other hand, comes from your *test* set.

That clarified, it should be obvious that these two numbers are not the same; on the other hand, and provided that both the CV procedure and the train-test split have been performed correctly, they should not be *much* different, too, which is arguably your case here.